# Why did Onin tell the Krimzon Guard about Jak's arrival?

Tags: jak-and-daxter

Been wondering this ever since I was a kid:

In Jak II, at the very beginning, it is hinted that Jak's arrival to Haven City was predicted:

- Errol says *"we've been expecting you"*
- Errol also says *"leave the rat* [Daxter]*, the Baron wants **him**"*
- Praxis says *"I was told this one would be different!"*

There is a wiki page (http://jakanddaxter.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Warrior_Program) stating

> It's not explicitly mentioned how Erol knew where and when to find
>   Jak, but the speed and specificity of their search makes Onin a prime
>   suspect: she informed the Program of Jak's existence in Daxter.

I didn't finish Daxter, and can't find a reference anywhere else. Why did Onin tell the Krimzon Guard about Jak's arrival?

Moreover, what were the details given, capable of making Praxis think that Jak "would be different"?

Answer (score 1):

For Praxis thinking that Jak "would be different", that would probably refer to how he was exposed to Light Eco during his fight with Mira and Gol which probably allowed him to survive the experiments

The fact Onin informs the program of Jak's "Existence" would imply that she knew about his return prior which could mean that she knows more about the what occurred in the past than anyone else as she would have known about Jak's being exposed to Light Eco and that they would find the Time Gate and return to Haven

she may also know that the events of Jak 2 is in part a paradox, if Jak didn't defeat Kor his young self and Samos would have never went back in time to eventually find the time gate which allows the Metal Heads to enter the world from the future which is what led Jak back to Haven